# Php mysql select and echo array multidimensional

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

i have a prblem of 5 hours aprox... I can Print an mysql select
to a table from one array before i combine... my code is:
in Cookies there are this array 
Array( [] => [1254] => 325 [2112] => 77 [354] => 2 )
where [1254 is cod of product] => 325 is quant

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
            <tr><!--prepare row of head cols html static--> 
              <td> COD</td>
              <td> PROD</td>
              <td>CAT</td>
              <td>**CANT**</td>
          </tr>
     <?php  
          ////array in cookie to variable php $rr
          $rr = $_COOKIE['coo'];
          foreach ($rr as &$arr){////for each element of $rr generate one register
            $SQL="SELECT cod_pro,name,cod_cat,('$arr') AS quant FROM products 
               WHERE cod_pro=".$arr." 
               ORDER BY cod_cat asc";
          $result=mysql_query($SQL,$lnk) ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  //if exist anyone 

while($registers=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    ////print each row here all right
 echo "<tr><td>".$registers["cod_pro"]."</td>"."<td>".$registers["name"]."/td>"
 ."<td>".$registers["cod_cat"]."/td><td>".$registers["quant"]."</td></tr>";
       ////$registers["quant"] i want add one col with this value from cookie
  ?>
    <?php }?>
    <?php }     
    } ?>
  </table>
```

The problem is $registers["cant"] how i can do the SELECT my sql, for give this output;
[] => [1254] => 325 [2112] => 77 [354] => 2

```
      COD (pk)   NAME         COD_CAT       **quant** This i can´t show
      --------------------------------------------
      1254      Car (bd)         1 (bd)      **325**
      2112      Cicles(bd)       2 (bd)       **77** 
      354       toys (in bd)     3 (bd)        **2**
```

Any idea Thanks

Comment: Oh my talk about spaghetti code!

Comment: whats ?? sorry my english please

Comment: Your english is a little too confusing to understand exactly what you are trying to ask.

Comment: i want SELECT from that array with that output  (i cannot show QUANT) value of array associate with value of SELECT register, when this register is a query from BD. In the example  [1254 is code of product] => 325 is quantity

Comment: "quant" field there arenot in BD, this field i want ADD to each register, values of "quant are value in ARRAY $rr"   [1254 is code of product] => 325 is quantity i want ASSOCIATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you are asking. I cleaned up your code, and made the fix I *think* your wanting.
There is no reason to try and pass data into that SQL query, just to pull it back out.

Just reference the data directly in the loop.

I dont have any idea what this code actually does, so what I wrote below may not work...

But its the best I can do from what I understand.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
       <td> COD</td>
       <td> PROD</td>
       <td>CAT</td>
       <td>**CANT**</td>
    </tr>
 <?php  

    $rr = $_COOKIE['coo'];
    foreach ($rr as $name => &$arr)
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT cod_pro,name,cod_cat FROM products 
                WHERE cod_pro=".$arr." 
                ORDER BY cod_cat asc";

        $result=mysql_query($SQL,$lnk) ;

        if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {  

           while($registers=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
           {

                echo "<tr><td>".$registers["cod_pro"]."</td>"."<td>".$registers["name"]."/td>"."<td>".$registers["cod_cat"]."/td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";

           } 
         }      
    } 
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: THANKS @APPLEHAT THIS LINE IS EXACTLY THE SOLUTION foreach ($rr as $name => &$arr)

Answer (score 0):

after doing the select, 
get the results and then do the for each loop with the results

Now you are going the reverse way

Also you are having a single tr against multiple tr in your loop.

First try to make flow chart, then code.

Suggest you to go through data structure books and try to code and solve problems there.